# Ho use SESSIONS to identify users without asking for credentials?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, session, cookies

I'm creating this website, and I want to track every visitor, so that I can insert that id into the products database, to show only the products that the specific user added to the shopping cart.

I'm using sessions but don't know how to pull the session for that specific user. since I usually assign a value to it. Hopefully my questions is not dumb

Comment: Please provide some code some people can actually help you

Comment: I start the session_start(), I know that creates a unique cookie in the server, how do I pull it off and use it? I'm trying to get the code so I don't have one.

Comment: Pretty sure the PHP manual has some good examples of using $_SESSION global var.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use sessions first you need to start them in every page where you want to use it like so:

```
session_start();
```

Then you can just create variables and give them values, for example:

```
$_SESSION['User_ID'] = XXXX; //Identification
$_SESSION['Profile'] = Admin; //Admin or Normal User
```

When the user makes the login just create a variable like 'User_ID' to store the value and then you can access it everywhere.

```
$id = $_SESSION['User_ID'];
$profile = $_SESSION['Profile'];
```

so

```
$id = XXXX;
$profile = Admin;
```

You just need to remember of starting it and finish it in every page:

```
session_write_close(); // To Finish
```

You should also destroy the sessions when you don't need them anymore but you will lose the data sessions. The best place is when user logout of the system.

```
session_destroy();
```

Hope it helped

Comment: Thank you that helped clarify what I'm doing!